# straight arrows in a tikz diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm using `tikz` to draw a diagram, but I need some help with aligning some text. Here's my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[black] (0, 2) -- (0, 0) node [pos=.5, sloped, above] (TextNode) {\itshape A};
    \filldraw[black] (0, 0) circle (2pt) node[anchor=west]{\scshape B};
\draw[gray] (0, 0) -- (2, -4) node[anchor=west]{C};
\draw[black] (0,0) -- (0, -4) node [pos=.5, anchor=east] (TextNode) {

        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node at (0, 1) (nodeLin) {\small \itshape some text here};
            \node at (0, 0) (nodeVI) {\small \itshape some other here};
            \node at (0, -1) (nodeR) {\small \itshape some here};

            \draw[->] (nodeLin) -- (nodeVI);
            \draw[->] (nodeVI) -- (nodeR);      

        \end{tikzpicture} } node[anchor=north]{D};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This is the output:

[image]

What I would need to get, is that the arrow is center-aligned, and it always goes straight down. How can I do that?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use a `tikzpicture` inside a `tikzpicture`. Here you have an alternative solution.

Command

```
\draw[black] (0,0) -- node[left=2mm] (nodeVI) {\small \itshape some other here} (0, -4) 
      node[below]{D};
```

draws the line from `(0,0)` to `(0,-4)` and writes `some other here` 2mm to the left of central position of this line. (A node between `--` and coordinate is equivalent to `pos=0.5`). After that, we can use this node as reference for upper or lower sentences.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[black] (0, 2) -- (0, 0) node [pos=.5, sloped, above] (TextNode) {\itshape A};
\filldraw[black] (0, 0) circle (2pt) node[anchor=west]{\scshape B};
\draw[gray] (0, 0) -- (2, -4) node[right]{C};
\draw[black] (0,0) -- node[left=2mm] (nodeVI) {\small \itshape some other here}
 (0, -4) node[below]{D};
\node[above= 5mm of nodeVI] (nodeLin) {\small \itshape some text here};
\node[below=5mm of nodeVI] (nodeR) {\small \itshape some here};
\draw[->] (nodeLin) -- (nodeVI);
\draw[->] (nodeVI) -- (nodeR);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

May this helps you

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[black] (0, 2) -- (0, 0) node [pos=.5, sloped, above] (TextNode) {\itshape A};
    \filldraw[black] (0, 0) circle (2pt) node[anchor=west]{\scshape B};
\draw[gray] (0, 0) -- (2, -4) node[anchor=west]{C};
\draw[black] (0,0) -- (0, -4) node [pos=.5, anchor=east] (TextNode) {

        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node [align=right] at (0, 1) (nodeLin) {\small \itshape some text here};
            \node [align=right]  at (0, 0) (nodeVI) {\small \itshape some other here};
            \node [align=left]  at (0, -1) (nodeR) {\small \itshape some here};
            \draw [->] (nodeLin) -- (nodeLin |- nodeVI.north);
            \draw[->](nodeVI) -- (nodeVI |- nodeR.north);      
        \end{tikzpicture} } node[anchor=north]{D};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```